# Possible to do conditions on a path_beg?

Tags: haproxy

I'm wondering if it's possible to add some conditional operators in a `path_beg` acl.

For example I'd like to do something like this:

```
acl myacl path_beg /samples { and !path_beg /samples/view }
```

Where the `myacl` is triggered for anything that lives at `/samples` but is not triggered if the path is `/samples/view`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can not be defined on the ACL level but when using the ACL in a rule:

```
acl myacl path_beg /samples
acl myacl_exceptions path_beg /samples/view

use_backend mybackend if myacl !myacl_exceptions
```

As you can see, you can define two separate ACLs which you then use to define a full condition. Note that in this case, the two ACLs are combined with a logically `AND`. There are other options to combine multiple ACLs. Please refer to the [documentation](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.2) for details.

Note that you can also use anonymous ACLs. An equivalent example with an anonymous ACL for the exceptions could look like this:

```
acl myacl path_beg /samples
use_backend mybackend if myacl ! { path_beg /samples/view }
```